# Sorting by Specific Column data using .csv in python

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I'm trying to order a .csv file with just over 300 entries and output it all back out ordered by the numerical values in one specific column under a dialect.
Here's the code I've written so far but it just seems to output the data as it went in

```
import csv
import itertools
from itertools import groupby as gb

reader = csv.DictReader(open('Full_List.csv', 'r'))

groups = gb(reader, lambda d: d['red label'])
result = [max(g, key=lambda d: d['red label']) for k, g in groups]



writer = csv.DictWriter(open('output.csv', 'w'), reader.fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(result)
```

There's only 50 rows in the whole file that contain a value under the dialect "red label" and all the others are left blank. 
It's in the Z column on the .csv(but not that last one) so I'd assume the index of the column is 25(0 being the first).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `groupby` isn't for sorting, it's for chunking an iterable.  From the docs for  [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby): "Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Full_List.csv')
df = df.sort('red label')
df.to_csv('Full_List_sorted.csv', index=False)
```

You may need to adjust the options to `read_csv` and `to_csv` to match the format of your CSV file.

Comment: I've tried using the pandas method you have told me about but whenever I run the script I get the error "No module pandas exists" even though I've installed it from my python directory using sudo apt-get install python-pandas

Comment: Which version of python and what operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 3.2 on Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Edit: I've figured out what the problem is in trying to run pandas. When I installed it it installed into my python2.7 folder but when I run my script it's running from the python3.2 folder which is in the same directory as the 2.7 version which is /usr/local/lib and I've no idea how to change my script to run from that directory

Comment: Finally got around the pandas error but the output is still the same as the above method that Steven gave me

Comment: By the same output, do you mean a ValueError?

Comment: No, I mean there is no change in the output. The file that's outputted is the exact same as the one that went in

Comment: Are the fields in the file not separated by commas?

Comment: I eventually got it fixed. Thank you very much for all the help Adam :)

Comment: `sort` appears to have been deprecated since this answer was published. Using `sort_values` instead works.

Answer (score 8):

`groupby` isn't for sorting, it's for chunking an iterable.  For sorting use `sorted`.

```
import csv

reader = csv.DictReader(open('Full_List.csv', 'r'))
result = sorted(reader, key=lambda d: float(d['red label']))

writer = csv.DictWriter(open('output.csv', 'w'), reader.fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(result)
```

*Note:* I changed your lambda to cast your character data to float for correct numerical sorting.

Comment: I've tried that and gotten the following error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
I changed the casting from float to str.
It compiled but it completely eliminated all values in the column it's sorting

Comment: From the `ValueError` it appears that `d['red label']` does not always return numeric data.  Do you have any empty fields?  As regards to "it completely eliminated all values in the column", I think that is not the case.  This code does not overwrite any values.  It would be helpful to see your actual data.

Comment: Yes. All but 50 of the entries within that column are just blank fields.

Comment: If those blank fields can be sorted as if they have a value of `0.0` change `float(d['red label'])` to `float(d['red label']) if d['red label']) else 0.0`.

Comment: @AzKai: Post the first ten lines of your file.  Something is not quite right here.

Comment: These are the first 2 lines(not enough comment space for all 10:
ID tag number genus species locality location name new register number x or series collector's name collection number no. cv donor donor's ref. number infrasp. rank epithet; infraspecific common name German name French name Irish name COUNTRY OF ORIGIN date of collection collection information accession status planting date red label X notes References synonym date of verification verifier's name Champion tree dimensions authority family
6994 4009 Abelia sp. BY Bothy 9                     check identity.        Caprifoliaceae

Comment: Or if needs be I can send you the file to have a look at it

Answer (score 2):

I found with testing that the following works on csv files that I have. Note that all rows of the column have valid entries.

```
from optparse import OptionParser
# Create options.statistic using -s
# Open and set up input file
ifile = open(options.filein, 'rb')
reader = cvs.DictReader(ifile)
# Create the sorted list
try:
  print 'Try the float version'
  sortedlist = sorted(reader, key = lambda d: float(d[options.statistic]), reverse=options.high)
except ValueError:
  print 'Need to use the text version'
  ifile.seek(0)
  ifile.next()
  sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda d: d[options.statistic], reverse=options.high)
# Close the input file. This allows the input file to be the same as the output file
ifile.close()
# Open the output file
ofile = open(options.fileout, 'wb')
writer = csv.DictWriter(ofile, fieldnames=outfields, extrasactions='ignore', restval = '')
# Output the header
writer.writerow(dict((fn, fn) for fn in outfields))
# Output the sorted list
writer.writerows(sortedlist)
ofile.close()
```